# YOUTUBE video channel functions requests

Tags: php, xml, api, youtube

I am looking to find a way to work with a particular channel on youtube
I want to be able to receive a list of videos in that particular channel in xml format
also would like to be able to receive the latest video or couple of videos

I searched through the youtube API but didn't find exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[Channel or User]/uploads
```

you receive a XML with 25 newest videos along with all their information 
also all the attributes and more documentation can be found here

```
[http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos][1]
```